# Get distinct values of specific column with max of different columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following `DataFrame`

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   A|   6|null|null|
|   B|null|   5|null|
|   C|null|null|   7|
|   B|null|null|   4|
|   B|null|   2|null|
|   B|null|   1|null|
|   A|   4|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

What I would like to do in Spark is to return all entries in  `col1` in the case it has a maximum value for one of the columns `col2`, `col3` or `col4`.

This snippet won't do what I want:

```
df.groupBy("col1").max("col2","col3","col4").show()
```

And this one just gives the max only for one column (1):

```
df.groupBy("col1").max("col2").show()
```

I even tried to merge the single outputs by this:

```
//merge rows
val rows = test1.rdd.zip(test2.rdd).map{
  case (rowLeft, rowRight) => Row.fromSeq(rowLeft.toSeq ++ rowRight.toSeq)}
//merge schemas
val schema = StructType(test1.schema.fields ++ test2.schema.fields)
// create new df
val test3: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
```

where `test1` and `test2` are `DataFrames`done with queries as (1).

So how do I achive this nicely??

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   A|   6|null|null|
|   B|null|   5|null|
|   C|null|null|   7|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Or even only the distinct values:

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|   A|
|   B|
|   C|
+----+
```

Thanks in advance! Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some thing like below :-

```
sqlcontext.sql("select x.* from table_name x ,
(select max(col2) as a,max(col3) as b, max(col4) as c from table_name ) temp 
where a=x.col2 or b= x.col3 or c=x.col4")
```

Will give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved like this:

```
df.registerTempTable("temp")

spark.sql("SELECT max(col2) AS max2, max(col3) AS max3, max(col4) AS max4 FROM temp").registerTempTable("max_temp")

spark.sql("SELECT col1 FROM temp, max_temp WHERE col2 = max2 OR col3 = max3 OR col4 = max4").show
```

Comment: Thanks! I just changed `spark`to `sqlContext` in my case and it worked.
Is there any best practice when to use udfs for `DataFrames` and when working with SQL in `sqlContext` of `tempTable`?